# How can I mix a video in Full HD (1920 x 1080) with a vid in HD (1280 x 720)

Tags: video, premiere, full-hd

I'm trying to export a video of Premiere CS6 and I am having some problems... My two cameras record in different size, and when I'm working with the clips on the program, everything looks great and works well, but when I export them, the clips that were for the Full HD camera doesn't looks like in the programe, they are kind of ampliated.

If someone understands what I'm saying and can help me, I would be grateful!
Thanks!!

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or describe your problem a little further? Mixing videos of different resolutions of course means that one of than has to be resized, which implies several problems, based on your description it's difficult to determine what exactly you were trying to do and where the problem lies ...

Comment: Ampliated sounds bad, but it's not actually a word in English.

Comment: @stib - I thought it was a perfectly cromulent word.

Comment: Well that ampliated quickly °v°

Comment: Either size up the 720p (1280x720) footage to 1080p (1920x1080) or vice versa.

Comment: @stib Wiktionary begs to differ: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ampliate#English

Comment: I stand corrected. My vocabulary has been ampliated, thank you. Does that mean the OP meant that the footage was stretched?

Comment: Dont forget you can also crop to avoid that ampliated look or having to use cromulent words to describe your issue :p

Answer (score 0):

At Premier Pro, see Effect control tab on the top left, select scale. Then you adjust the percentage of size of video match your sequences setting.
If your sequence setting are HD 1280×720 then you 0r FHD 1920×1080p videos all need to scale smaller. Final of your video will be 1280×720. Same to if your sequence setting in FHD then your HD video need to be scale up enlargement, it will blurer the videos, need to add smart sharpen at Effect tab below left to an adjustment layer .